# programmatically generate graphs and charts with c / c++

Tags: c++, c, charts

Is it possible to generate images that pictorially display data from data sets in memory?
I need to **generate charts and graphs** (jpeg / gif / png) to represent in-memory numerical data, produced in my server-side application, on demand. I can log this data into a file, and generate the charts using gnuplot, but then that requires another set of application process to be maintained and run, and I don't want to do that. I know images can be generated with libgd, but couldn't find any good examples of using libgd for making charts etc. I am looking for something that can be truly portable across operating systems.

Comment: I would go with gnuplot and pipes

Comment: @perreal: I think the asker is looking for more of a challenge.  Gnuplot is too easy, and you can't show off your programming skills that way.

Comment: There is another question where you might find an answer: [Graph drawing C++ library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/492893/237483)

Comment: I recommend you to use MathGL.

Comment: Thank you ALL very much, for pointing out the duplication. The suggested solutions - dislin, koolplot, ROOT, should be the right matches I guess. StackExchange surely is a good place to be! And thank you for pardoning my bad searching skills.